# Is there a way to track or view someones browsing history on Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, safari, ads

Is there a way to track someones browsing history, or emails opened etc via websites/cookies?

I noticed sometimes when I goto frequently visited sites, such as game websites, I eerily notice articles popping up related to things I purchase and get into. Sometimes it seems like it is too much of a coincidence and I am definitely being monitored.

I mainly do all my internet browsing on iphone safari in Incognito with google search engine.

I am wondering if some websites install some kind of software on the iphone itself to monitor what I purchase and view whether it be through safari or mail apps. I know this is a very real possibility since sometimes even though I browse on safari in incognito, i start seeing related ads in my yahoo app. I start seeing related articles in websites, actual articles and not ads. It just seems all too coincidental and creepy.

D&mn lead gen.

Does anyone know and also a way to stop it?

Edit

I am well aware of the many issues with privacy, but sometimes, like now, I feel I in particular am being tracked extensively. An example is i recently purchased something off a random online merchandise store and now all of a sudden the game website i goto has articles about special deals from this website I purchased from. They will get profit from lead gen. It seems too much of an invasion to ME in particular

Answer (score 0):

You are right... In a way, you are being watched. We all are being watched if you think that way. This is "the Privacy issue". [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com) partly solves the problem. Please take a look at it... You will get more info.

Comment: I am well aware of the many issues with privacy, but sometimes, like now, I feel I in particular am being tracked extensively. An example is i recently purchased something off a random online merchandise store and now all of a sudden the game website i goto has articles with this website I purchased from. They will get profit from lead gen ads. It seems too much of an invasion to ME in particular